# In multi process programming, what is the content of switching between different processes?

Tags: c

I came across an interview question: On Linux, in multi process programming, what is the content of switching between different processes? My answer is the memory used by each process. Is there an official answer?

Comment: An attempt at an official answer can be found [in this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch). It's not very good, and it's not very detailed, which is understandable because it's about switching in general. The details very much depend on the OS and the hardware.

Comment: I don't understand the question - "content" doesn't make sense.  In any case it seems like a more open-ended question, asking you to demonstrate a general understanding of how context switching works.  There isn't really an "official" answer to something like that.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.